# 3-D Loop comparison in 7-pt Stencil

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I carry out a 7-pt stencil update on two 3-D domains. The first one is `258x130x258`and the second one is `130x258x258`. Both of them have the same number of elements being updated. In C they are represented as contiguous arrays : `a1[258][130][258]` and `x1[130][258][258]`. Simply stated their `x-dimension` and `y-dimension` are exchanged but `z-dimension` (fastest changing index) is equal.

Loop 1:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 256 ; i++)
    for(j = 1; j <= 128 ; j++)
        for(k = 1; k <= 256; k++)
            a1[i][j][k] = alpha * b1[i][j][k] + (Omega_6) *(b1[i-1][j][k] + b1[i+1][j][k] + 
                                  b1[i][j-1][k] + b1[i][j+1][k] + 
                                  b1[i][j][k-1] + b1[i][j][k+1] +
                                  c1[i][j][k] * H);
```

Loop 2:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 128 ; i++)
    for(j = 1; j <= 256 ; j++)
        for(k = 1; k <= 256; k++)
            x1[i][j][k] = alpha * y1[i][j][k] + (Omega_6) *(y1[i-1][j][k] + y1[i+1][j][k] + 
                                  y1[i][j-1][k] + y1[i][j+1][k] + 
                                  y1[i][j][k-1] + y1[i][j][k+1] +
                                  z1[i][j][k] * H);
```

`a1, b1, c1` all have same dimensions and `x1, y1, z1` have the same dimensions. `alpha` and `Omega_6` are constants. Loop 1 runs `0.5 seconds` faster than Loop 2. *Why does this happen ?*

Comment: Did you measure them separately? Multiple times, I.e. is the difference statistically significant? It's probably related to caching.

Comment: @DanielJour: Yes the timings are measured separately for them. Each loop is executed thrice in the actual program. Yes the difference is statistically significant as in Multigrid even 0.5 seconds is a good difference (when you're looking at execution times of less than 5 seconds). I suspect its caching but I don't know *how*. My L1d cache is 32KB, L2 is 256KB and shared L3 cache is 2.5MB per core. Thanks for your comment :).